# Display and preserve model

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have a two stage process:

1. A user completes an application form which is stored in a db and an internal team validates the data at which stage the user is send an email link asking them to complete the application.
2. A page is displayed to the user containing all of the information that they originally supplied with a confirmation button.

My problem is on step 2, I'm populating a model on page load and displaying this information to the user but when the user submits the form the model being posted back is empty.

If I use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)` etc. then the model will still contain the value of the property but I all I need to do is display the values to them rather than give them the opportunity to amend them (they're actually not allowed to amend them at this stage).

Is there any helper that I can use for this or is there no way around this?

Thanks,
C

Comment: Lots of ways to handle. If you are trying to reuse the same view/partial, then make the fields readonly for the confirmation view. Otherwise, use hidden fields for the data you need back.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Rather than have a load of hidden fields I think that I'll pop the model into a session variable on page load and repopulate it on the post. Thanks.